# Facebook JSON API for 'Linting' URL

Tags: facebook, api

The [Facebook Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) does a terrific job of taking a URL and parsing / loading it into a title / description / image / etc. Does this API expose a JSON format or does a similar service exist for 'linting' URLs into more rich objects? I'm trying to do an iOS integration. Obviously I'd like to avoid parsing XML and extracting the metadata myself if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update

> “This Graph API endpoint is simply a call to: `POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true` The response from this endpoint will be a JSON object that contains all the information about the object that was scraped (the same data returned when the Object ID is read from the Graph API).”

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank's so much!